# what is meant by the space $BSU(2)$,

Tags: classifying-spaces

I am aware of the group, $SU(2)$, but I came across a space, $BSU(2)$, but I have no idea of what this stands for?

I noticed that $BSU(2) \cong \mathbb{HP}^\infty$, can any one please explain how is this if this is true?

Comment: No, $BG$ is the [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) of principal $G$-bundles.

Comment: P.S. $SU(2)$ is simply connected; it has no nontrivial double cover.

Comment: I made changes in the question, as it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Recall $SU(2)\cong Sp(1)$, the group of unit quaternions.  The (left) quaternionic projective $n$-space $\mathbb{HP}^n$ can be described as the quotient of the unit sphere $S^{4n+3}\subset\mathbb{H}^{n+1}$ by the (free continuous) scalar multiplication of $Sp(1)$ (on the left), hence $Sp(1)\to S^{4n+3}\to\mathbb{HP}^n$.  The scalar multiplication respects the inclusion $\mathbb{H}^n\to\mathbb{H}^{n+1}$, so taking limit we have principal bundle $Sp(1)\to\varinjlim_n S^{4n+3}\to\varinjlim_n\mathbb{HP}^n$, i.e.,
$$
Sp(1)\to S^\infty\to\mathbb{HP}^\infty.
$$
Since $S^\infty$ is contractible, we get $BSp(1)\simeq\mathbb{HP}^\infty$ (up to homotopy equivalence).

Comment: Thank you , but I don't fully understand the last line, how does the fact that $S^\infty$ is contractible help confirm $BSp(1) \simeq \mathbb{HP}^\infty$

Comment: By definition, we want the total space $ESp(1)$ to be a contractible space with a proper free continuous $Sp(1)$ action (since $Sp(1)$ is compact, any continuous action is automatically proper so I dropped that in the answer), and $S^\infty$ fills that role.  General theory says if a universal $G$-bundle $P\to B$ exists, then (a) $B$ can be taken to be a CW-complex; (b) a CW-classifying space $B$ is unique up to canonical homotopy equivalence; and (c) $P$ is unique up to $G$-equivariant homotopy equivalence.